# List of files with pending changes in VS2008/TFS to clipboard

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

When I right-click a solution in VS2008 and select Check In... I am presented with a list of changed files with check boxes and a comment area. (This is done against TFS.)

Our check-in process requires that we enter this list of changed files into the bug tracking ticket. This requires typing in the name of each each file: time-consuming and error prone.

Ideally I'd like to be able to select that list and copy it to the clipboard so that I can paste it into the bug tracking system.

Does anybody have a way that I can easily get that list into the clipboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use SnagIt for such things, it is really an amazing application.  They have non-free versions and a free version (instructions [here](http://www.labnol.org/software/download/free-download-snagit-with-serial-number/1841/)).  I don't know how I lived without it, honestly.

Among its features is the ability to scrape text from a window (like Windows Explorer folder view) which will probably meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know no standard way, how to do it. But you can create a tool to do this.

```
            string strServer = startInfo.Server;
            string strWorkspace = startInfo.Workspace;

            Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServer tfsServer = null;
            if ( false == string.IsNullOrEmpty( strServer ) ) {
                tfsServer = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServer( startInfo.Server );
                tfsServer.Authenticate();
            }

            Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer vcServer = null;
            if ( tfsServer != null ) {
                object obj = tfsServer.GetService( typeof( Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer ) );
                vcServer = obj as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer;
            }

            Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace workspace = null;
            if ( tfsServer != null && vcServer != null && false == string.IsNullOrEmpty( strWorkspace ) ) {
                workspace = vcServer.GetWorkspace( strWorkspace, tfsServer.AuthenticatedUserName );
            }

            List<string> pendingItems = new List<string>();
            foreach ( Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.WorkingFolder folder in workspace.Folders ) {
                pendingItems.Add( folder.ServerItem );
            }

            List<string> localFilePaths = new List<string>();
            string userName = tfsServer.AuthenticatedUserIdentity.AccountName;
            Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.PendingSet[] pendingSets = workspace.QueryPendingSets( pendingItems.ToArray(), Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType.Full, null, userName, false );
            foreach ( Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.PendingSet ps in pendingSets ) {
                foreach ( Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.PendingChange change in ps.PendingChanges ) {
                    localFilePaths.Add( change.LocalItem );
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, a big advantage your organization would have is if they also moved the bug tracking system over to TFS then when you check in the files you could associate that check-in with the work item (bug, task etc) and the association would be taken care of for you.  It would also allow lots of reporting etc etc - all good stuff.

Comment: I think that the reason that we haven't done that is because there are a number of projects based on other technologies (PHP etc.) that aren't using TFS but need to use the bug tracking system.

Comment: BTW, you can have all your technologies (including PHP) using TFS if they want to.  You'd certainly be getting a lot more value out of your investment in TFS.

Answer (score 2):

If your company has installed the Web Access Power Tool for TFS, then you could just paste a url into your bug tracking system that links back to the check in.

It would look like this...

**http://mytfs:8090/cs.aspx?cs=1234**

Saves time and has very little chance for error.

Ta.

Steve Porter

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you take a screenshot (alt+Prnt Scrn) of the checkin dialog and upload the image to the bug tracking system?

Comment: I had thought of that and was tempted to but that's been ruled out - thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2010 select all the files and then press `CTRL+C` to copy the file details to clipboard.